# Preventing default error logging in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

It seems that by default, Silex is logging all exceptions and errors. I would like to turn this off, so that the logs contain only the records that I make myself. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: create your own monolog provider by extending the default monolog provider and override the boot method , there is an app->error listener you can remove.

Comment: Thanks that worked. If you want, provide this info as an answer so we can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your own monolog provider by extending the default monolog provider and override the boot method , there is an app->error listener you can remove.

Answer (score 2):

Just after registering MonologServiceProvider, remove *monolog.listener* service:

```
$app->register(Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), ...);
unset($app['monolog.listener']);
```

You can also replace *monolog.listener* service with your own service.